# Typescript:error TS2314: Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript and i have written very basic code.

```js
class School {

    nameOfStudents: Array[string];
    noOfteachers: number

    constructor(name: Array[string], no: number) {
        this.nameOfStudents = name;
        this.noOfteachers = no;
    }

    printName():void{

        for(let i=0;i<this.nameOfStudents.length;i++){
            console.log(this.nameOfStudents[i])
        }
    }
}
let arr=["a","b","c","d","e"]
let school = new School(arr,100);

school.printName();
```

Where ever i have used the array i am getting the following error:

error TS2314: Generic type 'Array' requires 1 type argument(s)
Where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: That's not how you supply the specific type - did you mean `Array<string>`? Or just use `string[]`.

Comment: try to define array like this: `nameOfStudents : string[] = [];`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generic arrays must be defined as:

- `const arr = new Array<string>()`
- `const arr = string[]`

Answer (score 2):

Using the T[] sythax is recommended over Array< T > synthax

TSlint [rule](http://ttps://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/array-type/) "array-type": [true, "array"]:

For your code, Array[string] should be Array < string > in order to compile.

```
nameOfStudents: Array<string>;
noOfteachers: number

constructor(name: Array<string>, no: number) {
    this.nameOfStudents = name;
    this.noOfteachers = no;
}
```

The best practice would be something like this

```
class School {

    nameOfStudents: string[];
    noOfteachers: number;

    constructor(name: string[], no: number) {
        this.nameOfStudents = name;
        this.noOfteachers = no;
    }

    printName(): void {
        for (const studentName of this.nameOfStudents) {
            console.log(studentName);
        }
    }
}
```

I higly recommend you to install [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) for your project, it will help you to write clean Typescript code.

**EDIT 18/12/22: tslint is deprecated, use eslint instead**